# Designing 3 Billboards

Tags: print-design, dpi, bleed, document-setup

So I have to design 3 billboards and this is pretty much my first time doing it where it goes to print. I'm used to designing small scale stuff so this task is a bit daunting.

I would just like to know how much bleed I should allow for a billboard of say 9 metres by 6 metres and also at which sizes and dpi I should be working at. I read some of the other posts that mentioned taking down the size to 9cm x 6cm with an output of 300dpi or 900cm x 600cm at an output of 30dpi. I'm not sure.

Comment: Bleed, gutter, resolution etc. are printer specific. So this question should be directed to your billboard printer. Don't hesitate to ask just because you are afraid that you might appear ignorant.

Comment: This is an e.g. - http://dtph.com/HowTo/How%20To%20Prepare%20Billboard%20Artwork%20in%20Adobe%20Photoshop.pdf (PDF). By the way, don't think this is the answer to your problem ... the guidelines in this are for that particular printer. Your printer may have different specs.